# Integrating ng-packagr generated package with Angular CLI app: Module not found

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng-packagr

Here's a repo that reproduces it: https://github.com/dragonflypl/ng-packagr-issue

1. I've create a simple package `logging`.  `npm run build` generates the library + does `npm pack`
2. Then I generated `fooGui` with Angular CLI and installed library it via `npm run consume` that installs tgz
3. Running `npm run build` from `fooGui` throws:

> ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ngfactory.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'logging/src/modules/logging/logger/index' in
>   'C:\XXX\dev\ng-packagr-issue\fooGui\src\app' resolve
>   'logging/src/modules/logging/logger/index' in
>   'C:\XXX\dev\ng-packagr-issue\fooGui\src\app'   Parsed request is a
>   module   using description file:
>   C:\XXX\dev\ng-packagr-issue\fooGui\package.json (relative path:
>   ./src/app)
>       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration   after using description file:
>   C:\XXX\dev\ng-packagr-issue\fooGui\package.json (relative path:
>   ./src/app)
>       resolve as module
>         C:\XXX\dev\ng-packagr-issue\fooGui\src\app\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         C:\XXX\dev\ng-packagr-issue\fooGui\src\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         C:\XXX\dev\ng-packagr-issue\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         C:\XXX\dev\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         C:\XXX\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         C:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         looking for modules in C:\XXX\dev\ng-packagr-issue\fooGui\node_modules
>           using description file: C:\XXX\dev\ng-packagr-issue\fooGui\package.json (relative path:
>   ./node_modules)
>             Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           after using description file: C:\XXX\dev\ng-packagr-issue\fooGui\package.json (relative path:
>   ./node_modules)
>             using description file: C:\XXX\dev\ng-packagr-issue\fooGui\node_modules\logging\package.json
>   (relative path: ./src/modules/logging/logger/index)
>               no extension
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 C:\XXX\dev\ng-packagr-issue\fooGui\node_modules\logging\src\modules\logging\logger\index
>   doesn't exist
>               .ts
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 C:\XXX\dev\ng-packagr-issue\fooGui\node_modules\logging\src\modules\logging\logger\index.ts doesn't exist
>               .js
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 C:\XXX\dev\ng-packagr-issue\fooGui\node_modules\logging\src\modules\logging\logger\index.js doesn't exist
>               as directory
>                 C:\XXX\dev\ng-packagr-issue\fooGui\node_modules\logging\src\modules\logging\logger\index
>   doesn't exist

Any idea what I did wrong or it is a bug somewhere?

Comment: Instead of `"logging": "file:../logging/dist/logging-1.0.0-rc.1.tgz",` use npm link/unlink feature or publish logging to npm. I am not saying that is the problem but have seen build tools run into issues with `file:` repos.

Comment: BTW here is another one I wrote https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-library-builder that does similar stuff as `ng-packager` but you should open an issue on there site and try getting it fixed. If you run into any issues with https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-library-builder I can help.

Comment: The same thing happens with original packages published and installed via npm, but thx

Comment: @bhantol - could you have a look at my answer, I've fixed it , but I don't know why it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the culprit: in public api file, I have:

`export * from './src/modules/logging/logger';`

that accesses index.ts.

When I replaced it with explicit it with explicit exports:

```
export * from './src/modules/logging/logger/logger.service';
export * from './src/modules/logging/logger/log-level.enum';
```

then it works. But the question now is : any idea why? Because I don't know.

Comment: This is an (extremely frustrating) issue with the Angular compiler that I've only come across when using ng-packagr. Barrel imports are not supported, more info [here](https://github.com/abbazabacto/ngpackagr-barrel-issue).